# Wireless problem (it results always disabled)

Tags: networking

I'm new in Linux and ElementaryOS world, so I'm a little noob

I have a HP 250 G3, and I installed ElementaryOS in dual boot with WIndows 10.

The problem regards WiFi connection: even if "Wireless" is set on active (in the menu on the top right), it doesn't find any access point; furthermode if I go on settings --> network and select Wireless, it results as "Wireless is deactivated".
With the LAN connection everything works fine.

I think it may be a problem with network driver. 
The Network Board is a "Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe"

Anyone knows how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's blocked on the software level with `rfkill`.

Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829863/wi-fi-drivers-for-laptop-xiaomi-air-13) answer out. I guess it'll help you too.

Comment: ~$ rfkill list 0: phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no